# Which .NET Managed classes to initiate internet connection?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

Are there any .net classes that allow for controlling an internet connection? Such as connecting/disconnecting from a wireless connection?

Any details need to be useable in any .net framework version running on XP sp/3 or later windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

HttpWebRequest inherits from the abstract class [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) which is used for most high-level internet communications.

> "WebRequest is the abstract base class
>   for the .NET Framework's
>   request/response model for accessing
>   data from the Internet"

If you want lower-level but managed access to the WinSock layer then look in the [System.Net.Sockets namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx).

Comment: I may have confused the question by mentioning HttpWebRequest. Let me restate: Network streams returned from methods like myClient.GetStream() are somehow already associated with a network connection. What I'm looking for is to understand and manipulate that original association. For instance, the stream that is written to when calling write() on a stream returned from an open socket may be my internet connection through my network card. What if I wanted it to instead use a different network connection, or perhaps a different stream all together?

Comment: I re-stated the question removing the mention of WebRequest for clarity.